# DCC models in R: how is the first starting value chosen?

Tags: r, time-series, correlation, covariance-matrix, garch

The DCC model is defined through the proxy $Q_t$ as
$$Q_t=(1-\alpha-\beta) \overline{Q} +\alpha\epsilon_{t-1}\epsilon_{t-1}' + \beta Q_{t-1}$$which is then normalized to find the correlation matrix $R_t$
$$R_t=\frac{q_{ij,t}}{\sqrt{q_{ii,t}q_{jj,t}}}$$

I've been using the `rmgarch` package and its copula-garch commands (`cgarchspec` and `cgarchfit`) to couple time series with either a normal or Student-t copula and a DCC dependence structure.

All results are nice and everything, but my question is on a problem which is present also at the univariate GARCH level: how is $Q_0$ chosen for the first estimation of $Q_1$? I've been going through the `rmgarch` document and other references on the Internet but haven't found any relevant info.